# Unable to send mail trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: email, laravel-5.6, laravel-mail

I'm trying to send an email using Laravel 5.6. I created mail using `php artisan make:mail forgotPassword -m forgot_password`. for some reason i'm unable to use `php artisan make:auth for forgot password` and reset. Then i create a ForgotPasswordController to send the email.

```
use App\Mail\ForgotPassword;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
.
.
.
public function forgot_password(Request $request)
{
  Mail::to('christophersegoh@gmail.com')->send(new ForgotPassword);
}
```

i'm using mailtrap for now to check if it's succeed. my env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=00cb7939681e9
MAIL_PASSWORD=9232f1eb4a697
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

for some reason i got an error

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null